# How to achieve rotating only border and not the icon using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to rotate my border 135 deg on hover but icon rotate also and i want ONLY the border, i post the code if you can help me i will appreciate it,Thank you!

```
 My html: `
    <div class="container-fluid details-section">
      <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
       <div class="col-xl-2 my-auto box text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-guitar"></i>
      </div>
       <div class="col-xl-2 my-auto box text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-guitar"></i>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xl-2 my-auto box text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-guitar"></i>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>`

    And CSS: 
    
        `.details-section{
          background-color: rgb(83, 83, 83);
          height: 200px;
        }
        
        
        .box i{
          font-size: 70px;
          border: 2px solid #c49b63;
          color: black;
        }
    .box:hover i{
      transform: rotate(135deg);
    }
    `
```

Comment: Try putting the border on a pseudo element and rotating only that on the hover.

Comment: Just rotate the icon the same amount in the opposite direction.

Comment: @AHaworth Like .box::before?

Comment: Yes, but I like @Paulie_D suggestion better, it’s neater.

Comment: So i leave .box:hover i and i add i:hover transform rotate(-135deg)? @AHaworth

Comment: Try it. I’m afraid I can’t add a snippet as I am stuck on a touch device at the moment.

Comment: @AHaworth I tried but i think this solution doesnt work :/

Comment: Can you put what you have tried into a snippet we can run. It makes it much easier to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option with reverse `transform`. I updated the HTML to rotate an inner element instead of the `.box` itself to separate the bootstrap elements from the rotating elements.

```css
.details-section {
  background-color: rgb(83, 83, 83);
  height: 200px;
}

.icon-container {
  border: 2px solid #c49b63;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
}

.box i {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: black;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
}

.icon-container:hover {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.icon-container:hover i {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/4.6.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid details-section">
  <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
    <div class="col-sm-2 my-auto box text-center">
      <div class="icon-container">
        <i class="fa fa-guitar"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 my-auto box text-center">
      <div class="icon-container">
        <i class="fa fa-guitar"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 my-auto box text-center">
      <div class="icon-container">
        <i class="fa fa-guitar"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One more thing how i can also add transition when rotating the border? Thank you again!

Comment: I edited the snippet to add a transition. Be sure to add `transition` to both `.icon-container` and `.box i` elements, otherwise one will animate and the other will not and it will look odd.

Comment: I appreciate so much, thank you for the help, have a nice day!